# Has anyone here tried PHP On Pie?

Tags: php, frameworks, open-source

I created this framework to fill what I felt was a need for a PHP-like framework that was really efficient. My goal is to make it into a real open-source project, but since I have never launched a popular open-source project, I could use some feedback and advice.

My question is, has anyone here used it, and if so, what was your experience?

Whether you have or haven't, do you have any advice for the non-programming aspects? What is it missing, in terms of

- Documentation
- Out of the box ease of use
- Community features and support
- Whatever else I can't think of right now.

Basically any advice on how I can take it from its current state and make it at least somewhat popular?

`http://phponpie.com`

Comment: Do you have any unique features in comparison to ZF, Kohana, CI? If no then it is "just yet another framework".

Comment: To popularize it, make a freshmeat entry, host it on sourceforge/github/google in addition. You might need a forum, use an external service or build one atop your framework for extra cred (none of the big OOP frameworks has accomplished that yet). If you have some time extend your entry here: http://matrix.include-once.org/framework/view.php?name=pie - don't make everything green! What seems unique about your framework is the packaging as plugins. Distribution is seldomly considered by the big frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this before, but I wasn't sure at all why I should use this instead of Zend Framework or Symfony, so as zerkms said, it seems like just another framework.

The code quality has some question marks about it as well. The code seems to mix and match PHP4 and PHP5 styles (no visibility declaration on some class methods, some class constructors used PHP4-style constructors...) and it had inconsistent file naming (interface iDb in Db.php) and inconsistent coding style, even in the same file.

Not sure how easy it would be to unit tests apps written with this either.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to mention Symfony in my comment ;-)

Comment: So you are saying, that I should refactor the coding style to be entirely consistent? Basically most of those were conscious decisions. e.g. The visibility defaults to public so I only show private and protected visibility. And as far as iDb inside Db.php, it was just for efficiency so you wouldn't have to load as many files. But I agree - there might be better ways. I just made these decisions based on my own experience. Is that enough reason not to use something? I think Wordpress and Drupal have a worse coding style, but they are popular. What can I do to make it more popular?

Comment: These were just my observations of things that can be turn-offs for possible contributors or users of your code. The reason why people use WordPress despite this (myself included) is because the product itself is good - Easy to use, has plenty of features. You rarely need to touch the code of the product so it doesn't matter as much. Mario's comment on your question had some good points too in my opinion